# Simple arithmetic in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and in order to get familiar with it I'm doing some basic code katas. Currently, I'm doing the [Kata Potter](http://www.codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/index.pl?action=browse&id=KataPotter&revision=41) and I have the following snippet of code that I don't know what's wrong in it.

```
import Test.Hspec

priceOf :: [Int] -> Int
priceOf xs = 8 * (length xs) 

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  describe "Harry Potter book prices" $ do
    context "Simple discounts" $ do
      it "should apply a discount to two different books" $ do
        priceOf [0, 1] `shouldBe` 0.95 * 8 * 2
```

And when trying to run it with cabal, it ends up throwing the following error

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal '0.95'
In the first argument of '(*)', namely '0.95'
In the first argument of '(*)', namely '0.95 * 8'
In the second argument of 'shouldBe', namely '0.95 * 8 * 2'
```

Reading further on similar topics here and the chapter about `Converting numbers` on the Haskell wiki, I've found the `fromIntegral` function but still don't get it and I don't know how should be the correct way to apply basic arithmetic between different types in Haskell.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us `priceOf` method?

Comment: I have added the definition of `priceOf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that (deducing from the error message) `priceOf` returns an `Int` while `0.95 * 8 * 2` has the polymorphic type `Fractional a => a`, and `shouldBe` is forcing these types to be the same. But `Int` isn't a `Fractional` type, so you get "No instance for `Fractional Int`".

Ways to solve this:

1. Make `priceOf` return a `Fractional` type, e.g. `Double`, or
2. Convert `0.95 * 8 * 2` to `Int` using one of `round`, `floor` or `ceiling` depending on your requirements.